# Boolean difference acts differently for different planes in the same object

Tags: modifiers, eevee-render-engine

I've got on object made with two walls and a floor for a virtual room, shaded as an Eeevee shadowcatcher, and have created some transparent cubes to act as window openings in the walls. So, the room has Boolean modifier running for two of the window "cutout" objects on one wall, and they work great. When I move the cutouts into the wall, holes appear! Whoo hoo!

But if I copy one of these cutout objects and move it to the adjacent wall, Boolean difference doesn't work. It looks more like union, with "exact" box checked. I've tried copying the Boolean difference modifier to make sure settings are exactly the same, and they are.

It's just that the difference modifier works on one wall and the floor, but not the adjacent wall!

Here's a pic - you can see cutouts 1 & 2 work great, cutout 3 does not.
[image: Room with window openings]

Any ideas?

[Check out the video, too.](https://vimeo.com/495805135)

[Here's a video showing the normals of the cube.](https://vimeo.com/495867388) Sorry - don't know how to embed these videos!

You can see how the cube I'm trying to use as a "cutout" interacts with the various walls.

---

OK, solved! It was an issue of non-manifold geometry. I extruded the walls to give them some dimension, so now they have an official inside AND outside. Works now!

[image]

Comment: The normals on the mesh determine how boolean operations work flip the normals and try again.

Comment: I did this - flipped the normals back and forth, and nothing changed.

Comment: Don't use videos or external links. Use the tools from this site to add images that are displayed as part of the question. Some of us will not look at links or download files.

Comment: Gotcha. Need to figure out how to embed video!

What I did to solve this was to extrude faces to give the walls some dimension, and now my cutouts work fine on all walls.

So, it's a "non-manifold geometry" issue, I take it!